# Expose GRPC server through Ingress on Google Cloud

Tags: java, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, grpc

I'm trying to expose a GRPC Java service thought an Ingress to outside world from my GKE cluster.

The problem is that GKE's default implementation creates a health check that expect 200 response code on curling "/". It is expected and documented [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/master/docs/faq/gce.md#can-i-configure-gce-health-checks-through-the-ingress).

Unfortunately this seems not to work with [grpc-java](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java) implementation since it's not handling "/" GET requests.

GRPC itself defines a [health checking protocol](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/health-checking.md). But it's not supported either.

I wonder if there is a similar secret annotation like "kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name" but for disabling health checks at least(ideally overriding them).

Answer (score 3):

Seems at the moment GCP HTTP Load Balancers [doesn't support HTTP/2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/bfURoNLojHo). So I ended up simply by exposing my service through LoadBalancer instead of NodePort + Ingress.

Note: static IP you provide in `loadBalancerIP` should be **REGIONAL**. For a multi-region static IP my service's external IP was always in pending state.

Answer (score 1):

The health check can be changed by defining custom [liveness/readiness probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/). In this way, you can define custom endpoints to hit for the health check. Here's a sample from the documentation:

```
 livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /healthz
    port: 8080
    httpHeaders:
    - name: X-Custom-Header
      value: Awesome
  initialDelaySeconds: 3
  periodSeconds: 3
```

If you need something more powerful than a simple HTTP check, you can construct a probe with 'exec' instead of 'httpGet'. With exec, you can use Linux commands or a custom CLI script in your container to query your API or otherwise verify the state of your system. If the command/script returns 0, the pod is seen as healthy. This sample will view the pod as alive if a file exists at /tmp/healthy:

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - cat
    - /tmp/healthy
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 5
```